# Find Fault in Java Program Launch?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I created a quick program in Java just to get started with the GUI-based elements of Java before I start writing the actual program. In Netbeans, everything compiles perfectly, and the GUI has all of the elements I put into it, so there is not problem when I am using Netbeans.

However, upon building and packaging into the JAR, I have no result on open. I have tried to use Webstart and everything else I could think of, but I get no different result. The JAR does, however, change size along with the varying of my program, so I know something is working, I just must be missing a file or something of that nature.

**EDIT:**

The manifest says the following after the build (This is inside the JAR):

```
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_26-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: com.nmagerko.Execute
```

Comment: You need to change `${jnlp.codebase}` to actual directory name. Also, in Windows you must use `/` instead of `\\` in paths. Your jar doesn't work, because it was not correctly built.

Comment: @MockerTim, you must understand I did not put in that code. It is just output saying that it cannot find this according to what Netbeans preset it for.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a desktop application, don't try to use Webstart since your errors are coming from this. What problems do you have if you try to run the application as a simple non-webstart Jar? Do you specify the class with the main method in the manifest file?

Comment: @HoverCraft Full Of Eels I know, I have a simple JAR that I was trying to use, but I cannot access the Manifest until after compilation of the classes. Is there a way to access it from inside Netbeans?

Comment: What text is in your `manifest.mf` file after compilation. Add it to your question, please.

Comment: Does this text is from the `manifest.mf` file that the jar-file contains? Or it resides in your project's folder? I.e. there is `<project_name>/manifest.mf` file, and `<project_name>/dist/<project_name>.jar/META-INF/manifest.mf`, by default. Which one's text you've added to your question?

Comment: I have both of those you listed. The one in the JAR says what my main class is. The Class-Path is empty, however.

Comment: So, can you add the text of the jar that contains `Main-class:` directive?

Comment: Yes, I enabled it to be edited in Netbeans, but the Main-Class is already in the JAR's manifest.

Comment: It seems that we don't understand each other. Please, add the text, that your `<project_name>/dist/<project_name>.jar/META-INF/manifest.mf` file contains, to your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5559/discussion-between-mockertim-and-nmagerko)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Using help from @Mocker Tim, I found that using `java -jar program-name.jar` allowed for details that Netbeans did not catch.

This ended up being the fact that my path to my icon had one too many "/"'s, and removing that one slash allowed for the program to be jarred correctly.

Comment: java webstart is not very helpful in case of problems.  A tip when things are a bit strange:  Double check with a XML tool that the JNLP  is valid, javaws doesn't check.

Comment: I do agree. I didn't really know what else to do, so I did that. I know what to do now!